# "data:," in address bar chromedriver (maven project with testng)

Tags: testng, selenium-chromedriver, maven-plugin

When I'm starting the test I see "data:," in the chrome address bar. 
I'm creating Maven project with TestNG and only try to open the google index page

```java
public class GetBrowser {

protected WebDriver driver;

@Parameters("browser")
@BeforeTest
protected WebDriver getDriver(String browser){
    if (browser.equals("chrome")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/user/IDEA/drivers/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if (browser.equals("firefox")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/user/IDEA/drivers/geckodriver");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
 }
}
```

```java
public class OpenIndexPageTest extends GetBrowser {

@Test
public void openPage(){
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    String titleActual = driver.getTitle();
    String titleExpected = "Google";
    Assert.assertEquals(titleActual, titleExpected);
 }
}
```

My testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="ChromeTestExample">
     <test name="ChromeTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.fozzy.autotest.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Also, I've added dependencies in pom.xml from maven repository (org.testng and org.seleniumhq.selenium last versions)

IDEA returns **java.lang.NullPointerException.** And I don't understand where is the problem.

Trace

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5) on port 11290
Only local connections are allowed.
Dec 16, 2018 12:48:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5) on port 15730
Only local connections are allowed.
Dec 16, 2018 12:48:47 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fozzy.autotest.OpenIndexPageTest.openPage(OpenIndexPageTest.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

info:
ChromeDriver 2.45 (last release)
Selenium-java 3.141.59 (last release)
testng 6.14.3 (last not beta-version)
java version "1.8.0_191"
IDEA 2018.3.1(CE)

Please help, thanks!!

Comment: What you have shared is not sufficient enough to help figure out what is wrong. Can you please edit the question and include the complete sample along with the full stacktrace of the error message?

Comment: Thank you, done. I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your test code. You are using `@BeforeTest` annotation to instantiate your browser. TestNG runs a `@BeforeTest` annotated method only once per `<test>` tag.

So if your package is having more then one test class, the driver instantiation logic from your base class `GetBrowser` will not executed from the second class onwards leading to `NullPointerException`.

Please use either `@BeforeClass` or `@BeforeMethod` annotation instead.

Comment: Krishnan Mahadevan, thank you very much, you helped me a lot.